# Buefy Change Locale

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, momentjs, buefy

I want to change the language a date picker is displayed in based on a moment() locale. Not just a translation of the date chosen by the user, but the date picker itself.

I have a datepicker with the following date-formatter

```
   <b-datepicker
      :date-formatter="(date) =>  moment(date).locale('ar').format('YYYY-MM-DD')"
   ></b-datepicker>
```

But am unable to get the date picker to change language. I've made sure to import and set the moment locale before hand.

Answer (score 1):

Set locale, then **format** the date and then `return` it.

`moment(date).locale('ar').format('LLLL');`

You can format the date in [different formats](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format).

**UPDATE**:
To change `moment` language just define reactive `data` property (for example `lang`):

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lang: "ar"
    }
  }
}
```

and in your `template`:

```
<b-datepicker
  :date-formatter="(date) =>  moment(date).locale(lang).format('YYYY-MM-DD')"
></b-datepicker>
```

So whenever you change `lang`, your date will be reformatted accordingly to your selected language.

Comment: Thank you, this does work when I pick a date. But apologies for not being clearer in my question, I can see how it was badly worded. What I meant is to be able to change the language the dates and numbers are displayed in, of the datepicker itself and when the datepicker is open. Would you happen to know whether that is possible with this component?

Answer (score 0):

Use `month-names` and `day-names` to translate the date picker. See [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/datepicker).
With moment, you can do that way:

```
<b-datepicker
  :date-formatter="(date) => moment(date).locale(lang).format('YYYY-MM-DD')"
  :month-names="moment.locale(lang).month()"
  :day-names="moment.locale(lang).weekdaysShort()"
/>
```

But you should define locale(lang) at a global scope instead in component template...